# how to check if a notification exists in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working with the default notifications that come with laravel.
I know the methods to check if a notification is read, but I don't need that.
What I need is to check if a notification has been created before.

The default notification table in laravel is this one:

**notifications migrate**

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The notification I created returns an array that is added to the data field of the notifications table.

The array is inserted like this:

**data:**

{"id":77}

I have tried to check if the relation exists but I can't access the array value.

I have tried all these ways

```
$destination = User::findOrFail($model->user_id);
$previusNotification = $destination->notifications()->where('data.id', $model->id)->count() > 0;
or
$previusNotification = $destination->notifications()->where('data[id]', $model->id)->count() > 0;
or
$previusNotification = $destination->notifications()->where('data['id]', $model->id)->count() > 0;
```

but it always returns :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'data.id'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check whether JSON string from `data` field in notifications table has an `id` that matches `$model->id`. You can use `whereJsonContains()` to extract value from JSON string.

```
->whereJsonContains('data->id', $model->id)
```